# How to convert the float32Array format of native html5 recorded audio to proper bytes for Google Speech-to-Text service?

Tags: javascript, python, websocket, audio-streaming, google-speech-api

If you follow this tutorial: https://medium.com/ideas-at-igenius/delivering-a-smooth-cross-browser-speech-to-text-experience-b1e1f1f194a2 you will manage to create a script processor to which you add a listener

```
scriptProcessor = inputPoint.context.createScriptProcessor(bufferSize, in_channels, out_channels)
//...
scriptProcessor.addEventListener('audioprocess', streamAudioData)
```

Inside the callback by calling this line: `callback_param.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0)` one receives a javascript Float32Array which by looking at the data seems to contain float numbers from -1.0 to +1.0

Therefore streaming this to the backend which in turn streams it to Google Speech-To-Text service you are getting nothing (as expected)

Google Speech-To-Text service, at least in Python, for streaming input expects a byte-string in a wav format which contains the sound in the rate that it was specified (i.e. 16000Hz). Note that if in the backend you stream it a file this is working ok.

This conversion has failed: Float32Array -> Int16Array -> byte-string

Has anyone find what are the appropriate conversions for the above to work ?

Alternatively are you aware of a simpler more robust path for: Microphone in browser -> stream data via websocket to backend server -> stream data to Google Speech-To-Input service -> get responses as expected ?

---

Edit: Adding python code for Recognition Config of Google speech api

```
config = types.RecognitionConfig(
        encoding=enums.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16,
        sample_rate_hertz=16000,
        language_code=self.language_code)
```

Comment: What is the exact format Google is expecting?  16 bits per sample, 16 kHz sample rate?  Also note that you need to know what the original sample rate is, if you expect to resample correctly.

Comment: Hi @Brad thanks for your response. See an edit in my question where I explain what is the configuration for Google speech client

Comment: Do you know the endian-ness of what's expected?  (Probably little endian, but just checking.)

Comment: Hi @Brad thanks for the tip. Yes I have taken this into account with both little and big endian. Little "sounds" better, meaning we are closer to the final sound file. Currently I am also considering how python treats numbers... Would it make sense in python to convert from range -32768...32767 or from range 0..65535 to a short in order to keep its binary representation

Answer (score 1):

Ok, did some digging, found the [actual documentation](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/rest/v1/RecognitionConfig#audioencoding) which has the proper information.

> `LINEAR16` - Uncompressed 16-bit signed little-endian samples (Linear PCM).

The key parts being:

- 16-bits per sample
- Signed
- Little-endian

So, what you need to do is scale your floating point values (`-1.0 ... 1.0`) to integers between `-32786` and `32767`.

There isn't any built-in JavaScript method to do this for you.  Your conversions between Float32Array and Int16Array don't work because you'll just end up with values approximating `-1`, `0`, and `1`.  The other reason you can't use Int16Array is because it's [endianness is platform dependent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Int16Array)!

What you need to do is get cozy with ArrayBuffers and manipulate them with a [DataView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DataView).  Take each sample, do some math, write the bytes, move to the next sample.  When you're done, both XHR and the Fetch API support sending an ArrayBuffer as the HTTP request body.  Or, you can instantiate a new Blob with that ArrayBuffer and do other things with it.